# dynamic header image for blogengine.net

Tags: asp.net, blogs, blogengine.net

searching for a method to change a header image if I click on a link in BlogEngine.Net.
Let's say if I am at / and go to /page/about.aspx the header image should change.

Answer (score 0):

This will require custom code for the page.  There is nothing built in for this, and since the header image isn't a server object by default you will need to make it a server object.  Then have some sort of settings file that stores what header image links to what page.  You can then plug in an admin page to manage that settings file.